# How do I keep the axes from changing dynamically when I plot an animation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, axes

I'm plotting an animation of a function dx/dt and I've set the axes, but when the animation runs, the axes change dynamically, according to the plot. How do I fix this problem?

```
clear all;

%Equation variables:
s = 0;
r = 0.4;

%axes limits:
xmin = 0;
xmax = 2;
ymin = -.05;
ymax = .2;

%s limits:
smin = 0;
smax = 1;
s_steps = 100;

%our x-space:
x = linspace(xmin, xmax, 100);

%Let's try different s-values and plot as an animation:
for s=linspace(smin, smax, s_steps)
    counter = counter + 1;

    %dx/dt:
    dxdt = s - r.*x + (x.^2)./(1 + x.^2);

    figure(1),    
    subplot(2,1,1)
    axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax]);    
    plot(x, dxdt);


    title(strcat('S-value:', num2str(s)));

    hold on;
    y1 = line([0 0], [ymin ymax], 'linewidth', 1, 'color', [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 'linestyle', '--');
    x1 = line([xmin xmax], [0 0], 'linewidth', 1, 'color', [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 'linestyle', '--');
    hold off;
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply reverse the order of the "axis" command and the "plot" command. When you use "axis" before "plot", "plot" overrides the "axis" command with default axes. Switching these two lines will fix the problem.

However, if you want to animation individual points, there is also a "set" command which works wonders for neat animations. Check this out:

```
% data (Lissajous curves)
t = linspace(0,2*pi,50) ;
x = 2 * sin(3*t) ;
y = 3 * sin(4*t) ;

figure % force view
h = plot(x(1),y(1),'b-',x(1),y(1),'ro') ;
pause(0.5) ;
axis([-3 3 -4 14]) ; % specify a strange axis, that is not changed

for ii=2:numel(x),
  % update plots
  set(h(1),'xdata',x(1:ii),'ydata',y(1:ii)) ;
  set(h(2),'xdata',x(ii),'ydata',y(ii)) ;
  pause(0.1) ; drawnow ; % visibility
end
```

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/270439

Comment: I think I should add that other than plot this is the same case with commands like "rectangle" and "fill" or even "axis equal"  use "axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])" after all of them! thanks :)